# Continuity(?) of induced group representation in the isometries of $L^p$

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, ergodic-theory

Let $G$ be a topological group which acts on a measure space $(X,\mu)$ by measure preserving transformations. It's well known that this induces a representation $\pi$ of $G$ in $O(L^p (X,\mu))$, the group of linear isometries on $L^p (X,\mu)$, for any $1\leq p<\infty$.

My question is, under what circumstances do we have the following continuity property? Namely for each $f\in L^p (X,\mu)$, $g\mapsto \pi (g) f$ is continuous?

Edit: another, fancier way of saying this is that $\pi : G \rightarrow O(L^p (X,\mu))$ is continuous provided that $O(L^p (X,\mu))$ is endowed with the strong operator topology.

Comment: Does "topological group acts on $X$ preserving $\mu$" means $\mu(A) = \mu(g A)$ and when $g \to 1$ and $\mu(A) < \infty$ then $\mu(g A \cap  A)\to \mu(A)$ ?

Comment: @reuns That is what I meant, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easier than expected.

It suffices to check that for any $g_0 \in G$, and any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $g_0$ such that for any $g\in U$, $\Vert \pi(g)f - \pi(g_0)f \Vert_p <\varepsilon$. Since $G$ is a topological group, it actually suffices to pick $g_0 = e$.

The induced representation $\pi$ is given by $\pi (g) f(x) := f(g^{-1} \cdot x)$ for $f$ a point realization of an element of $L^p (X,\mu)$. It follows that for any indicator function of a measurable set $\chi_A$, $\pi(g) \chi_A = \chi_{gA}$. Compute that if $\mu(A) - \mu(A\cap gA) < (\varepsilon / 2)^p$, then $\Vert \chi_A - \chi_{gA}\Vert_p < \varepsilon$. Therefore it suffices to pick $U$ to be a small enough neighborhood around $e$ that $\mu(A) - \mu(A\cap gA) < (\varepsilon / 2)^p$, which we can do by assumption. In other words, as $g\rightarrow e$ in the topology of $G$, we have that $\pi(g)\chi_{A} \rightarrow \chi_A$ in $L^p$.

The same argument works for any simple function via the triangle inequality, and then by the density of simple functions, it also holds for any $f\in L^p(X,\mu)$ that $\pi(g)f\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ as $g\rightarrow e$, so we're done.

Comment: I think you should restrict first to a compact, use that the convergence of $\pi(g) \chi_A \to \chi_A$ is  "uniform in $A$", then apply the density of simple functions argument, then use the density of $L^p(K)$ for $K$ compact in $L^p$

Comment: Why is that necessary?

Comment: Because your $\epsilon$ depends on $A$ so the continuity extends to finite linear combinations of $\chi_A$ but not to infinite linear combinations.

Comment: Sure, but a simple function is only a finite linear combination.

Comment: The problem is "then by the density of simple functions, it also holds for any $f \in L^p$", there you need that $\epsilon$ is locally uniform in $A$

Comment: @reuns I think the solution is fine as is. Take $f \in L^p$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Take $s$ simple so that $||f-s||_p < \epsilon$. Then since we have the result for $s$, take a nbhd $U$ of $e$ so that $g \in U \implies ||gs-s||_p < \epsilon$. Then, for $g \in U$, $||gf-f||_p \le ||gf-gs||_p+||gs-s||_p+||s-f||_p \le 3\epsilon$.

Comment: Well no ok its fine. The isometry condition on simple functions is strong enough, because those are not overlapping when approximating $f$

Comment: @reuns why did you get suspended / temporarily banned from MSE?

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful comments.